# Sandbox version for AWS RedShift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have been using RedShift for a few months and I like it. But I need to add some tests around it and I am not sure what the most cost effective way of doing it is. I can only think of using one server RedShift cluster as Sandbox but that seems to be too costly even if I only use it during testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Databases in Redshift cannot 'see' each other and cross-database queries are not supported.  Therefore we simply have 'development', 'test' and 'production' databases on the same cluster.

When we're ready to push to production we:

- take a snapshot
- drop production
- rename test to production

This generally works fine for use because we find Redshift to be over-provisioned on storage, i.e., filling our nodes to their max storage capacity does not provide acceptable performance.

NOTE: You cannot drop your "master" database defined when the cluster was created. If you are using that as your primary database you will have to unload your cluster and recreate it for this approach to be viable.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from AWS RedShift forum: "There is no way of creating a sandbox version of Redshift. We'll add this to our backlog of feature requests"